# Como puedo sumar dos filas en SQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
id  Nombre  monto  
1   David  $500.00   
2   Andres $100.00  
3   Pedro  $600.00
```

Que tal amigos me pueden ayudar quiero sumar el monto de David mas el de Andres y eso enviar a otra tabla.
Lo que quiero es hacer como un tipo de transferencia es decir David tiene 500 y hago una transferencia de 200 a Andres y Andres tenga en total 300 
Por favor ayuden con eso o tal vez una mejor idea!!!

Comment: que estructura tiene la tabla destino a donde deseas enviar la información?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(monto) FROM tabla WHERE id IN (1,2)`

Comment: esta informacion va hacia otra tabla q se llama monto

Comment: la tabla se llama movimientos
id monto
1  
2

Comment: por favor enseñanos como es la estructura de la tabla destino en la que quieres generar el ingreso de la suma, identificando los campos y tambien en el de la tabla 1 que muestras de momento.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO sumas (cliente,monto) VAULES SELECT 'David', SUM(monto) FROM dinero WHERE id IN (1,2) Eso es igual que yo diga: INSERT INTO sumas (cliente,monto) VALUES ('david', (500+100))